# What does $0 and $1 mean in sorting in Swift 2.0

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, quicksort

Lots of people use `$0` and `$1` when sorting. It does not work for me. Here is the code that some people use.

```
images.sort({ $0.fileID > $1.fileID })
```

`images` is the array and I assume that `.fileID` is a field within that object. I want to sort my array of `oneCells` structs named `spend`.

```
struct oneCell{
    var date = NSDate()
    var money = Int()
}

var spend = [oneCell]()
```

I want to sort the array by date. How would I do that?

Comment: Your title and the question body do not match. Are you asking what `$0`, `$1` are (it *is* documented in the Swift book) or why your sorting does not work?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I noticed your title doesn't cover your question - if you click the Edit button, you can edit your question and change it into something more relevant. (How to sort an array by date in Swift, or something like that).

Comment: show the sorting you tried and explain what error you get

Answer (score 1):

It's Shorthand Argument Names

> Swift automatically provides shorthand argument names to inline
>   closures, which can be used to refer to the values of the closure’s
>   arguments by the names $0, $1, $2, and so on

Answer (score 1):

These are placeholders for values passed into a closure. They are labeled by position instead of being named. `$0` is the first argument to the closure, `$1` the second, `$2` the third, and so on. In this case `sort` takes two arguments. `$0` is the current element of the `spend` array and `$1` is the next. You would call `sort` like this.

```
let sorted = spend.sort{$0.date.timeIntervalSince1970 > $1.date.timeIntervalSince1970}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you:

```
struct oneCell{
  var date = NSDate()
  var money = Int()
}

var Spend = [oneCell]()
Spend.sort({ $0.date.compare($1.date) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending })
```